# TypeError when creating a property and initialising it with an array element

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties

I am writing my very first program in JavaScript, the idea is to create a function taking an array of integers and and making a list (data structure) with property values took from the array elements (have no idea of how I can do it iteratively).
The list would be something like this:

```
{
value: 1,
rest: {
    value: 2,
    rest: {
        value: 3,
        rest: null
    }
}
}
```

I am getting an error that I don't fully understand.
This is the program:

```
function arrayToList(list, array, n)
{
    list.value = array[n];

    if( n < array.length - 1 ) arrayToList(list.rest, array, n+1);
}

const array = [1,2,3];

let list = {};

arrayToList(list, array, 0);

console.log(list);
```

And this is the error:

```
list.value = array[n];
           ^
TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined
```

I found the following definition on the web:

> In JavaScript if a variable has been declared, but has not been
> assigned a value, is automatically assigned the value undefined .
> Therefore, if you try to access the value of such variable, it will
> throw Uncaught TypeError cannot set property of undefined .

I am not sure whether the `undefined` refers to `list.value` or `arra[n]`, but as far as I know (very little of JS) the statement is legitimately creating and initialising the `value` property of the `list` object, so the problem should be `array[n]`.
But `n` is an integer ranging from `0` to `array.lenght - 1`, so `array[n]` can't be undefined.

Please explain me how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is that the problem isn't occurring on the first iteration, but that of the second.

Your call to `arrayToList(list, array, 0)` is fine.  But, inside that function, there is a recursive call to `arrayToList(list.rest, array, n+1)`.  `list.rest` isn't anything.

I'm honestly not really sure what you're expecting to do in this case.  It isn't clear what your expected input/output should be.  I think you might be interested in looking these functions, which help you with whole arrays:

- [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
  Enables you to process each and every item in the array, returning a new array.
- [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
  Takes the whole array and allows reduction down into a single value.  (Seems to be closest to what you're asking... reducing down to a single object.)

Comment: Oh thank you so much! You are right, I never say anything about what `list.rest` is, so I can't use it like it was an object. I solved the issue by calling `arrayToList(list.rest={}, array, n+1);` (is there a better way to let the program know that `list.rest` is an object?). And I learnt that I can't print nested objects straight away, I needed `let str = JSON.stringify(list); console.log(str);`